# How to resolve JScript.NET assembly reference error JS1259?

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, jscript.net

I have this small app copied from a [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=_ybRMWJufiEC&pg=PA308&lpg=PA308&dq=%22listing+15.1+launching+a+basic+windows+form%22&source=bl&ots=UF1a15tXdh&sig=Vc8FmlajxNLf4nQTiaBfKJ1d1K4&sa=X&ei=PzYSUPCdDoiCmQWEk4HYAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22listing%2015.1%20launching%20a%20basic%20windows%20form%22&f=false):

```
import System;
import System.Drawing;
import System.Windows.Forms;

public class BasicForm extends Form 
{
    public function BasicForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private function InitializeComponent() : void 
    {
        this.Text = "Basic Windows Forms";
        this.Height = 400;
        this.Width = 500;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    }
    public STAThreadAttribute() static function Main(Args:String[]) : void 
    {
        Application.Run(new BasicForm());
    }
}

BasicForm.Main(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
```

When I try to compile it with jsc, I get this error:

> error JS1259: A referenced assembly depends on another assembly that is not referenced or could not be found

What's causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 8):

Import "Accessibility" namespace.

The code compiles using jsc.exe v2.0.50727 and v4.0.30319 when
Accessibility namespace is imported.

Without it the compiler generates the following:

> ```
> Microsoft (R) JScript Compiler version 8.00.50727
> for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 2.0.50727
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1996-2005. All rights reserved.
>
> error JS1259: A referenced assembly requires you to also reference 'Accessibility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
> ```

OR

> ```
> Microsoft (R) JScript Compiler version 10.00.30319
> for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework version 4.0.30319
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> error JS1259: A referenced assembly depends on another assembly that is not referenced or could not be found
> ```

`import Accessibility;`

Comment: thanks, i was becoming a bit annoyed by this too..